# How to view the process step by step of a function in R?

Tags: r

Df:

```
df <- tibble(
  a = c("z", "x", "y"),
  b = c("m", "n", "o"),
  c = c("p", "q", "r")
)
```

-I would like to see the result of `names(.)` (to inspect) in:

```
df %>% 
  set_names(c(names(.)[1], unlist(.[2, 2:3])))
```

-I know it is `c("a", "b", "c")`, or the result in `unlist(.[2, 2:3])`. This is an example, I want to apply the idea in any operation in R. Is there something out there? I want to have a deep sense of what some function is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the [boomer package](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/boomer) by @Moody_Mudskipper:

[image: boomerlogo.png]

#### Installation

Install with `remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/boomer")`

#### Examples (from github):

```
library(boomer)
boom(1 + !1 * 2)
#> 1 * 2
#> [1] 2
#> !1 * 2
#> [1] FALSE
#> 1 + !1 * 2
#> [1] 1

boom(subset(head(mtcars, 2), qsec > 17))
#> head(mtcars, 2)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> qsec > 17
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
#> subset(head(mtcars, 2), qsec > 17)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

# You can use boom() with {magrittr} pipes, just pipe to boom() at the end of a pipe chain.
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>%
  head(2) %>%
  subset(qsec > 17) %>%
  boom()
#> head(., 2)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> qsec > 17
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
#> subset(., qsec > 17)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> mtcars %>% head(2) %>% subset(qsec > 17)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#If a call fails, {boomer} will print intermediate outputs up to the occurrence of the error, it can help with debugging:
"tomato" %>%
  substr(1, 3) %>%
  toupper() %>%
  sqrt() %>%
  boom()
#> substr(., 1, 3)
#> [1] "tom"
#> toupper(.)
#> [1] "TOM"
#> Error in .Primitive("sqrt")(.): non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Boomer prints the output of intermediate steps as they are executed, and thus doesn’t say anything about what isn’t executed, it is in contrast with functions like lobstr::ast() which return the parse tree.

Apparently boomer doesn't 'play nice' with the set_names function; here is a similar example:

```
df %>% 
  names(.)[1] %>% 
  boom()
#>names(.)
#>[1] "a" "b" "c"
#>.[names(.), 1]
#> A tibble: 3 x 1
#>      a
#>  <dbl>
#>1    NA
#>2    NA
#>3    NA
#>df %>% names(.)[1]
#> A tibble: 3 x 1
#>      a
#>  <dbl>
#>1    NA
#>2    NA
#>3    NA
```

Comment: It's very close to what I want, thanks. Btw, to me, boomer plays nice with set_names.

Comment: Please, let me know if you know other packages that do similar things.

Comment: This is the only package that I use for this purpose - it's likely that there are others though

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but `lobstr::ast()` shows the abstract syntax tree that R creates to determine how the various inputs and functions in a call are related.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/become-a-better-r-programmer-with-the-awesome-lobstr-package-af97fcd22602

```
lobstr::ast(df %>% 
              set_names(c(names(.)[1], unlist(.[2, 2:3]))))


█─`%>%` 
├─df 
└─█─set_names 
  └─█─c 
    ├─█─`[` 
    │ ├─█─names 
    │ │ └─. 
    │ └─1 
    └─█─unlist 
      └─█─`[` 
        ├─. 
        ├─2 
        └─█─`:` 
          ├─2 
          └─3
```